# It does not enter in setState() method

Tags: flutter, dart, methods, setstate

I have the following code in Flutter. The variable checkValue is set to false and the variable newValue is optional, so I have to check if it is null or not. Then, I change checkValue to the value of newValue inside the setState() method. My problem is that it jumps the setState() method and does not change the value.

Can anyone tell me why that happens?

```
CheckboxListTile(
     title: const Text('Preferences'),
     value: checkValue,
     onChanged: (newValue) {
        if (newValue != null) {
           setState() {
             checkValue = newValue;
           }
        }
     },
     controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
),
```

I have tried to set the value with a condition like that:

```
CheckboxListTile(
     title: const Text('Preferences'),
     value: checkValue,
     onChanged: (newValue) {
        if (newValue != null) {
           setState() {
             checkValue = newValue ? true : false;
           }
        }
     },
     controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
),
```

It was normal it doesn´t work xD

Answer (score 1):

The `setState` format will be

```dart
setState(() {
  ///jobs
});
```

For your case

```dart
setState(
  () {
    checkValue = newValue;
  },
);
```

Comment: I literally can't see an answer of yours without voting it up, keep it up king

Comment: Thanks! I was so frustrated that I wasn't seeing it hahahaha

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [StatefulWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

you're not calling `SetState` properly:
replace this:

```
   setState() {
         checkValue = newValue ? true : false;
       }
```

with this:

```
   setState(() {
         checkValue = newValue ? true : false;
       });
```

Comment: Thanks! I was so frustrated that I wasn't seeing it hahahahaha